# ESRGAN : Required same input and output size

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-resizing, generative-adversarial-network

I am using the github ESRGAN of https://github.com/peteryuX/esrgan-tf2/blob/master/train_esrgan.py in tensorflow, and my **inputs and outputs have the same size.** I already have low_resolution and high_resolution images.

However, when using the code, the generator multiplies by 4 the image, which I want it to be the exact same size. So I can't re insert the generated image in the discriminator.

For example my batch if of size `(8, 128,128, 1)`, and when passing in the generator, it output `(16, 512, 512, 1)`. The discriminator takes a size of `(None, 128, 128,1)`.

I would like that it doesn't upsample, but I feel that it is only what it does ...

The generator is :

```
def RRDB_Model(size, channels, cfg_net, gc=32, wd=0., name='RRDB_model'):
    """Residual-in-Residual Dense Block based Model """
    nf, nb = cfg_net['nf'], cfg_net['nb']
    lrelu_f = functools.partial(LeakyReLU, alpha=0.2)
    rrdb_f = functools.partial(ResInResDenseBlock, nf=nf, gc=gc, wd=wd)
    conv_f = functools.partial(Conv2D, kernel_size=3, padding='same',
                               bias_initializer='zeros',
                               kernel_initializer=_kernel_init(),
                               kernel_regularizer=_regularizer(wd))
    rrdb_truck_f = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [rrdb_f(name="RRDB_{}".format(i)) for i in range(nb)],
        name='RRDB_trunk')

    # extraction
    x = inputs = Input([size, size, channels], name='input_image')
    fea = conv_f(filters=nf, name='conv_first')(x)
    fea_rrdb = rrdb_truck_f(fea)
    trunck = conv_f(filters=nf, name='conv_trunk')(fea_rrdb)
    fea = fea + trunck

    # upsampling
    size_fea_h = tf.shape(fea)[1] if size is None else size
    size_fea_w = tf.shape(fea)[2] if size is None else size
    fea_resize = tf.image.resize(fea, [size_fea_h * 2, size_fea_w * 2],
                                 method='nearest', name='upsample_nn_1')
    fea = conv_f(filters=nf, activation=lrelu_f(), name='upconv_1')(fea_resize)
    fea_resize = tf.image.resize(fea, [size_fea_h * 4, size_fea_w * 4],
                                 method='nearest', name='upsample_nn_2')
    fea = conv_f(filters=nf, activation=lrelu_f(), name='upconv_2')(fea_resize)
    fea = conv_f(filters=nf, activation=lrelu_f(), name='conv_hr')(fea)
    out = conv_f(filters=channels, name='conv_last')(fea)

    return Model(inputs, out, name=name)
```

**EDIT :**

I deleted these lines :

```
fea_resize = tf.image.resize(fea, [size_fea_h * 2, size_fea_w * 2], method='nearest', name='upsample_nn_1')
fea_resize = tf.image.resize(fea, [size_fea_h * 4, size_fea_w * 4],method='nearest',name='upsample_nn_2')
```

and kept the convolutions layers "fea"

**It worked !**

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can just average and downsample right?

Comment: Yes, but I would be afraid that it changes all the final result and purpose of the network

Comment: you can use a linear or convolutional layer to downsample, so that the network learns to downsample without destroying information

Comment: By deleting the "fea_resize" layers, for example ? As result, only the convolutions are left ?